# Find the max distance of any two points in a point cloud?

Tags: algorithm, max, point-cloud-library

I have a point cloud and I want to find the max distance between any two points in this cloud.

The algorithm came to my mind is to write two "for" loops and compare every distances. But I guess that is not smart enough...

Is there any existing function in PCL to do this? Or any idea of better algorithm?

Comment: Check out http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~michiel/lecturenotes/ALGGEOM/diameter.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The farthest points are members of convex hull.
So you can [build convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) for point cloud, the walk with [rotating calipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers) to get needed point pair